# How to setup Maven POM file with System Properties to inpurt parameters in Java?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to get input parameters from system properties that I set in maven POM file.

my POM look like

```
<systemProperties>
   <property>
      <name>number 1</name>
      <value>${number 1}</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>number 2</name>
      <value>${number 2}</value>
   </property>
</systemProperties>
```

When I run my test, this will be my maven goal

```
clean install -Dtest=RunTest test -Dnumber1=2 -Dnumber1
```

Now how can I write my java test code to get number1 and number2 from system properties?

```
public void addNumbers () {
    System.out.println(number1+number2);
```

}

**Do I need to use surefire plugin in my project to make it work?

Comment: `System.getProperty()` sounds fitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to pass System properties to your test cases, which are invoked by surefire plugin you need to configure surefire plugin to pass properties like

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <number1>1</number1>
            <number2>2</number2>

          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Can I get the variable number1 by String param1 = System.getProperty("number1"); right?

Answer (score 2):

In pom.xml we can configure like this:-

```
<project>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-DaddProp=true</argLine>
                <argLine>-DmultProp=false</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In java code for getting system properties:-

```
System.getProperty("addProp");
System.getProperty("multProp");
```